# Go: Can't pipe output from git to custom pipe

Tags: go, exec, stdout

I'm trying to forward the Stdout of "git clone somerepo ./" to log. Unfortunately, only the first line gets piped and everything else discarded.

```
package main

import (
    "os/exec"
    "log"
)


type pipe struct {}

func (p *pipe) Write(d []byte) (n int, err error) {
    log.Printf("Git subcommand: %s", d)
    return len(d), nil
}

func main() {
    e := exec.Command("git", "clone", "https://github.com/some/repo", "./DATA")
    p := &pipe{}
    e.Stdout = p
    e.Stderr = p
    _ = e.Run()
}
```

This code results in:
    2015/04/06 16:47:19 Git subcommand: Cloning into './DATA'...

Whilst a slight modification:

```
    e.Stdout = os.Stdout
    e.Stderr = os.Stderr
```

Prints out the correct result (but in the output of the cmd line, not a custom pipe)

```
Cloning into 'D:\Local\Temp\915593bb-0aae-4678-adf0-56930d519ee1'...
remote: Counting objects: 118, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done.
rRemote: Total 118 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0), peceiving objects:  38% (45/
Receiving objects:  40% (48/118)
Receiving objects: 100% (118/118), 22.35 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (53/53), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Cloning repository was successful
```

In both cases, the repository got cloned successfully, just the output isn't being catched right.

`CombinedOutput()` as well as `Output()` have the same broken behaviour:

```
func main() {
    o, err := exec.Command("git", "clone", "https://github.com/some/repo.git", "./DATA").CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Printf("%s", o)
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

Using scanners doesn't help either:

```
func main() {
    e := exec.Command("git", "clone", "https://github.com/some/repo", "./DATA")
    op, _ := e.StdoutPipe()
    ep, _ := e.StderrPipe()
    go func() {
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(op)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            log.Printf("Scanner got: ", scanner.Text())
        }
    }()
    go func() {
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(ep)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            log.Printf("Scanner got: %s", scanner.Text())
        }
    }()
    _ = e.Run()
}
```

Results in:

```
2015/04/06 16:54:21 Scanner got: Cloning into './DATA'...
```

Comment: Done, however it *should* work, because other messages get fine through, even when sent after running git.

Comment: i've updated to code to be less and better readable..check again :)

Comment: Git doesn't print the extra output if it's not connected to a TTY, use the `--progress` option.

Comment: @JimB you are a scholar and a god. Thank you :)